# What conditions could cause a Java Thread to return unexpectedly?

Tags: java, multithreading, distributed

This issue has come up in a distributed-multithreaded application I'm developing, where threads can appear to randomly return during distributed task execution.  Assume that every thread in this application uses the same basic code as the block below:

```
public class ExecutionThread extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            try{
                //task submitter app dumps all Tasks in to a queue.  We retrieve
                //those tasks here one-by-one and run them:
                Task t = priorityBlockingQueue.take();

                //execute is abstract, so it could potentially do anything here:
                t.execute(); 
            } catch(Throwable e){
                //task submitter app will be able to access the Throwable later:
                t.setUncaughtThrowable(e); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I should note that the Task class is abstract and very simplistic - it only has the execute() method which is abstract, so I didn't feel it necessary to post the code for it here.

I know that some crazy things can happen in the JVM, but this code to me seems fairly bulletproof, in that the thread should never return unless the JVM it's running in dies.  In actuality, we're seeing threads still return **without their respective JVMs dying** and can't pin down the cause.  To make matters worse, we can't see the console for these threads because they are being spawned as child processes on remote machines.  We've tried logging the throwable, but nothing gets printed to file.  Any ideas on what might still cause this thread to return?

Comment: What do you mean by "return" here? Return with no exceptions?

Comment: Yep - no exceptions get thrown, the run() method just finishes.

Comment: what is setUncaughtThrowable ?

Comment: It's just a method that allows my thread to tell the application that a Task failed.  The Task ultimately gets returned to the submitter after execution - the submitter checks to see if the Task has a non-null Throwable in it to verify that the task was actually completed.

Comment: @BenLawry - how does that work, then?  Presumably, the Task contains a submitter reference and can signal it somehow that the task is complete/failed. What's in there? An event that is called on catch?  If the task completes without an exception, how is the submitter notified?  Seems to be a lot missing here...

Comment: @MartinJames Not to mention he is probably getting a compiler error saying `t cannot be resolved to a type` compiler error in the catch clause

Comment: Martin - the reverse of your comment is true.  The submitter would maintain references to all of the Tasks it wishes to submit.  You're right that there is a lot more going on here than the example I've provided, but to do so, I'd have to include thousands of lines of proprietary code.  I wanted to keep this example simple because I've distilled this problem down to the code listed above.  You may assume there are no compiler errors, although my original post did contain the error mentioned by John Vint because of a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be an `Exception` in the `catch` clause.

Comment: ummm no. if an exception is thrown in your catch clause..then it will bubble out according to your code.

Comment: @Daniel paul is right.  What if a NullPointerException occurs in the setUncaughtThrowable() method?

Comment: setUncaughtThrowable handles null cases, so an NPE will never be thrown.  It simply stores a reference to the Throwable in the argument.

Comment: @BenLawry What about an OutOfMemoryError, or a StackOverflowError?  Unless we know more about what is going on we can only guess.

Comment: @John Vint - yeah, I'm basically just guessing here too - I'm thinking that it's probably an OutOfMemoryError, because this only started happening when we increased the data flow through the submitter.  It's just weird that the logger fails to print out anything - my guess is that if it's an OutOfMemoryError, and the logger requires more objects to be created in the logging process, then it makes sense that the trace would never get logged.

Comment: you could try to run the JVM in debug mode so that when this happens again you can take a look at the threads.

Comment: @BenLawry That is exactly right, you are observing the underlying issue with catching a Throwable.  I would suggest catching RuntimeException and letting the Task handle that.

Comment: I wish we could do that.  The JVM that is running the "ExecutionThread" is ultimately spawned by a call to ProcessBuilder's start() method, from within another JVM.  Ultimately, this ExecutionThread is part of a much larger system that spawns new JVMs for different applications that wish utilize a shared set of machines on a distributed computing cluster, simultaneously.  Because different applications have different class  dependencies, we spawn new JVMs to prevent these applications' dependencies from interfering with each other...  it's a giant can of worms...  LOL

Comment: @John Vint - I guess where we differ here is that this thread is pretty much guaranteed to not be running in the same JVM as the task submitting application.  It would be nice for that submitting application to know if its resources crashed because of memory problems.  Currently, the only thing the submitter sees is that task execution hangs.  The task never actually completes, and because the thread died, tasks remain in the queue, preventing the submitter from completing.

Comment: @Paul Nikonowicz (and John Vint too), thanks for your time - this is a good discussion and it's nice to bounce ideas off of experienced developers, even if we don't ultimately reach the desired solution.  I'm going to upvote all of your comments, your efforts are appreciated :)

Comment: 'I'm thinking that it's probably an OutOfMemoryError, because this only started happening when we increased the data flow through the submitter.' - sounds more like a race to me..

Comment: -1 -> +1 I misunderstood the comment. I thought it was meant as "don't catch Trowable, but Exception".

Comment: @Martin James - I suppose it could be, if the Tasks are piling up in the PriorityBlockingQueue faster than they can be executed, but we're fairly confident that this isn't happening.  We've set the ExecutionThread's JVM's memory to a couple of gigabytes and we're only submitting a few tasks with tens of megabytes of data apiece at a time to the queue.

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz I never did determine exactly what was causing this issue, but your answer is probably the most likely answer for anyone else who might come across this question.  I believe the thread was just dying because it had run out of memory, but there was no indication that any additional Throwables were being thrown inside my catch statement.  Truly bizarre...